# How can I convert a rate of black hole mergers into an estimate for the number density of black holes?

Tags: black-holes, estimation, dark-matter

There's an estimate from the recent detection of intermediate-mass black hole mergers that there are roughly $0.13^{+0.3}_{-0.11} Gpc^{-3} yr^{-1}$ [similar events a year](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aba493).

I'm wondering how to convert this merger rate into a number density of these intermediate-mass black holes, and preferably an estimate for the amount of dark matter $\Omega_{DM}$ that can potentially be due to these black holes. Clearly the larger the rate the more black holes there must be, but I don't know how to estimate it.

Comment: Are you looking for the population of the remnant black hole (100 and a bit solar masses or so). Or the population of the merging black holes (60-80 or so solar masses)?

Comment: @mmeent I'm looking for an estimate of $\Omega_{DM}$. Either of those should work to give an estimate.

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to estimate this, especially since it is very well possible that binaries that merge (in a reasonably short time) are atypical and not very representative of the general population.

Comment: Here is a paper that discuss the merger rate estimates of primordial black holes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12685, which may be helpful